# Python Import From Specific Location (Multiple Libraries Installed)

Tags: python, path

I have installed a library say (mylib) to the default installation directory /usr/bin/... and then, I installed the same library to a different folder by using:

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/tmp/python/
```

so, right now, I have TWO EXACTLY THE SAME library installed on different folders.

However, I don't want to delete either of them. 
I want to call the version which is from the /tmp/python/mylib, how could I do it in my python script.

```
#PSEUDO CODE
mypath = "/tmp/python/"
import mypath.mylib
...
```

Comment: Install virtual environment, that will solve the crux of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp/python/')

import mylib
```

Or change environment variable PATH when run the script:

```
$ PATH=/tmp/python/ you_script
```

But it is better to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org).
And [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org) maybe.

Comment: How do you know it is loading from /tmp/python instead of the default directory?  you insert the /tmp/python/ directory to be the first element in the path. So python will read it first?